# Continuity and open subsets

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am totally lost with the following proof. 
 I want to show that if a function $f : X \to R$ is continuous with $f(x) \gt 0$ for a particular $x \in X$, where $X$ is a metric space, then we have an open subset $U$ containing $x$ in $X$ with $f(z) \gt 0$ for all $z \in U$.

I know that for every open subset $U$ of $X$, the set $f^{−1}(0)$ is itself open in $X$, but I guess I don't get the starting point for this. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Let $\epsilon=f(x)/2$.

Comment: There are some quantifiers missing in your question. For example, is the statement $f(x) > 0$ true **for every** $x\in X$ or is it only true for a **particular one value** of $x$?

Comment: $f^{-1}(0)$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: @5xum true, sorry! It is for a particular value of $x$

Comment: @banan What about $z$? Is if for all or for some?

Comment: @5xum for all possible $z \in U$

Comment: I think you mean "for every open subset $U$ of $\Bbb{R}$,  $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$". If so, can you think of a good $U$ to choose?  (The existence of an $x$ such that $f(x) > 0$ is actually irrelevant, since the empty subset of $X$ is open.) If not, then you probably mean that $f$ is only known to be continuous at $x$, and it is unclear what your last sentence is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider $\epsilon=f(x),$ and keep in mind that $f$ is continuous at $x,$ in particular.

Comment: Thank you! However, I still seem to be a bit confused. Choosing $\epsilon$ like above and the definition of continuity I would have for $\delta > 0$ that  $|x-y|< \delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|< \frac{1}{2} f(x)$. I guess I totally miss the intuition behind it

Comment: Well, how would you describe the set $\{y\in X:d(x,y)<\delta\}$?

Comment: Or, more to the point, what *kind* of set is it?

Comment: ok, it is the open ball around $y$. So this is the open subset $U$,  but how do I connect that to the $\epsilon$?

Comment: Well, what are you trying to show about all $y\in U$?

Comment: that for all $y \in U$ we have $f(y) > 0$, but how can I connect this with $\epsilon$ ?

Comment: Well, given *any* $\epsilon>0,$ how would you express $\bigl\lvert f(x)-f(y)\bigr\rvert<\epsilon$ without using the absolute value bars?

Comment: I would express it as $N_\epsilon (f(x))$ and the continuity would imply $f(N_\delta (x)) \subseteq N_\epsilon(f(x))$ which would imply that the $U$ is the open ball around $x$ and for $y \in U$ we have $f(y)>0$ because it somewhere arbitrarily small around the $x$? Thank you for all the patience. I appreciate it!

Comment: I don't mean the set of all $y$ satisfying the inequality. I mean how would you express the inequality in a different way, with no absolute value bars?

Comment: you mean $\sqrt{(f(x)-f(y))^2} < \epsilon$?

Comment: I mean $$-\epsilon<f(x)-f(y)<\epsilon.$$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: From continuity  there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Then $U=\{y\in X:d(x,y)<\delta\}$ is an open subset of $X$. Now choosing $\epsilon=f(x)$ and rewrite $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ to $-f(x) < f(x)-f(y)<f(x)$. Further rearranging gives $-2f(x) < -f(y) < 0$ and thus $f(y)>0$ for all $y \in U$. I hope that get's it kindof. Thank you for all the patience again, I was really on the wrong track :)

Comment: Nicely done! Way to keep with it. Basically, I discovered $\epsilon=f(x)$ by imagining what the set $U$ would look like on the real line for a general $\epsilon,$ then noticing that $0$ would be in $U$ for $\epsilon>f(x),$ while $U$ has only positive elements otherwise.